# How to break up a long string of text which correspond to another string of text?

Tags: python

I have a text file that has two parts, `sentence_str` which consist of

```
This is a long sentence
This is another long sentence
And another one
```

and a `label_str` that consists of

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

how do I break the `label_str` so that it outputs corresponding to the length of `sentence_str`

```
This is a long sentence
This is another long long sentence
And another one

1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10 11
12 13 14
```

Comment: Do the lengths always match? And also: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: the lengths always match yes. I really don't know the Python functions well but as of now I'm trying with res = len(sentence_str.split()) to print label_str base on the number of string in each row but it's not working well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this using regular expressions:

```
import re

s="""This is a long sentence
This is another long long sentence
And another one"""

p,n = re.subn("\w+",'{}',s)
print(p.format(*range(1,n+1)))
```

[`re.subn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.subn) returns a tuple of the string after substitution and the number of substitutions

I used `re.subn` to generate a pattern `p` that can be used by [`format()`](https://pyformat.info/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use the .split() function. Keep each sentence (and the numbers) as string variables (this can be done through casting), and split by spaces, which looks like `myList = sentence_str.split(" ")`, this will a return a list of each word in the sentence. You can then just find the length of the list and use that to tell you how many numbers you need to put in each line of `label_str`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence_str = """This is a long sentence
                  This is another long long sentence
                  And another one"""
label_str = []
index = 1
sentence_str = sentence_str.split()

for i in sentence_str:
    label_str.append(index)
    index += 1
```

Output would be:

```
>>> print(label_str)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: Your solution solves for an index per character not per word.

Comment: how does this provide the same response as what the OP is asking for?

Comment: OP was unclear. Length usually refers to character count, not word count.

Comment: @MilesB sorry i didn't know better my bad